# Empty QueryString parameter

Tags: asp.net, query-string

#### The Problem

What is the proper way to check for the `foo` parameter in the following url's querystring using asp.net?  Is this even possible?

```
http://example.com?bar=3&foo
```

I have tried checking `Request["foo"]` as well as `Request.QueryString["foo"]` and I get `null` for both.  I have also tried populating a `List` with the values from the `QueryString` collection but as I mention below, it does not include the value.

#### The Question

I understand that there is no value, but shouldn't `Request["foo"]` return an empty string rather than `null`?  Is there a way to find out if a querystring key exists even if it has no value?

#### Notes

I found [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=377511) that `Request.QueryString.AllKeys` includes `null` for blank querystring parameters.

#### [edit]

As stated below by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12725/james-curran) and [Dreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44084/dreas-grech) a Regex to parse the raw url might be the best (and possibly only) approach.

```
Regex.IsMatch(Request.RawUrl, "[?&]thumb([&=]|$)")
```

Comment: What's the point of checking if a query string exists but is empty?  It's value (lack of value actually) is just as useless.

Comment: @Dreas, I assume that there is an implied "=true" at work (while the complete absence of a foo parameter is an implied "foo=false")

Comment: bool doesFooExist = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("foo=") >= 0 ? true : false; //will return true even if it doesnt have a value

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `null` as the key for the `NameValueCollection` and it will give you a comma-delimited list of parameter names that don't have values.

For `http://example.com?bar=3&foo` you would use `Request.QueryString[null]` and it would retrieve `foo`.

If you have more than one parameter name without a value, it will give you a value that is comma-delimited.

For `http://example.com?bar=3&foo&test` you would get `foo,test` as a value back.

**Update:**

You can actually use `Request.QueryString.GetValues(null)` to get the parameter names that don't have values.

Comment: Better really late than never I guess... :-)

Answer (score 9):

`Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]` will return the query string, complete, as a string.  Then search it using a Regex or IndexOf

Answer (score 7):

You get null because the `foo` parameter doesn't have a value with it.

...What's the problem exactly?

If you still want to check for its existence (although it lacks a value), try something like this:

```
bool doesFooExist = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("foo=") >= 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: I would like to check for a querystring key value even if it has no value.  I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Dreas is correct.  Variable "bar" has a value but foo does not.

Comment: Right, there is no value for foo.  However, I can find no reference to foo other than in the raw url.  A blank parameter is a parameter nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

QueryString["Bar"] will return 3 because it has the value 3 associated with the variable Bar.  However, Foo will return null because their is no value and when you are calling QueryString on a variable or key, you are querying for the value, not the key, so that is why you are returning null.

Answer (score 0):

query string is probably a waste one. If you use Request.Params[""] or iterate it, then you will find your desired one. Its really handy than other things.

Let me know if you need any help in this.