# Classic Asp - Empty QueryString Parameter

Tags: forms, asp-classic, http-post

I'm try to achieve in classic asp what has been done here in ASP.NET

[Asp.net - Empty QueryString Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400364/asp-net-empty-querystring-parameter)

So if i have a page question.asp

```
<form action="result.asp" method="POST">
Name:<input type="Text" name="name" maxlength="30"><BR>
Age:<input type="Text" name="age" maxlength="10"><BR>
Sex:<input type="Text" name="Sex" maxlength="10"><BR>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit"><BR>
</form>
```

And nothing is input in e.g.  'Sex' text box I stil need to know that it was sent.  e.g.  name=karl&age=39&sex=

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the post method, you should look into the Request.Form to get the parameters passed. The following code will print the keys/values received, including empty ones. Watch out though, it will also return the submit input !

```
Dim i
for i = 1 to request.form.Count 
   response.write request.form.Key(i) & " " & request.form.Item(i) & "<br />"
next
```

**Edit**: The same goes for Request.QueryString